# Limiting the print out of letters

Tags: php, drupal, pagination, alphabetical

I am trying to limit which letters print out according to whether there is information to print.  I.E. If there are no entries for "Y"  then there shouldn't be a "Y" in the listing. below is the code that I have that is working correctly for filtering.  It submits a call to the server which only responds with the entries starting with the submitted letter.

```
  // contextual filter list 
  $filters['contextual'] = array(
    '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('contextual_filter_list'),
        ),
    '#type' => 'container',
    );
  $alphabets = range('A', 'Z',);
  foreach ($alphabets as $value) {
    $filters['contextual'][$value] = array(
    '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('contextual_letter'),
        ),
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $value,
    '#title' => t($value),
    '#submit' => $value, 
    '#name' => 'Select',
    );
  }

// GET company list for A-Z filter bar
  $value = $_GET["Select"];

  $qry = db_select('cloud_computing_capability_data', 'cd');
  $qry -> fields('cd', cloud_computing_data_company::db_fields());

  // condition to query all or a single letter for companies
  if ($value != 'View All'){
    $qry -> condition('company',$value.'%','LIKE');
    };
```

It prints out this:

```
A | B | C | D | E | F | G |......
```

I need it to print out

```
 A | B | C | F | G |......
```

if there are no entries for "D" and "E"

Comment: Where is your print code?

Comment: this is part of a Drupal module.  The print is custom built into another part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could tweak your database query to return only the letters you want or you could always use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and ignore the entries that dont have values.

```
$result = array_filter($filters['contextual']);
print_r($result);
```

Or Perhaps something around this lines

```
$result = array_filter($filters['contextual'], function($a){
    return !empty($a['the_key_you_need_to_check']);
});
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to query the database. Since I don't know your database structure or the framework you are using, I will write the simple, sql query to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(main_letter) 
FROM `the_table`
WHERE 1 -- add your conditions here, if any
ORDER BY main_letter ASC
```

You can also get the main letter from a substring. It would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LEFT(name, 1))
-- rest of query
```

Good luck !

It's up to you to adapt this query to the ORM you are using.